# No 'wlan0' on 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers

Just installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 32bit on my "mature" Asus X50R laptop.  Basically working fine and I'm using it to write this post, with a wired network.

However wireless doesn't work.  The hardware seems to be detected and has a driver ("wl"):

```
mark@LaptopLinux:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=wl latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:fa9fc000-fa9fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Attansic L2 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: a0
       serial: 00:1e:8c:96:87:93
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl2 driverversion=2.2.3 duplex=full firmware=L2 ip=192.168.1.73 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:40 memory:feac0000-feafffff memory:feaa0000-feabffff
```

and the drivers seem to be in place

```
mark@LaptopLinux:~$ lsmod | grep wl
wl                   3999690  1 
lib80211               14040  1 wl
cfg80211              409394  1 wl
```

but the wireless interface doesn't show up:

```
mark@LaptopLinux:~$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:8c:96:87:93  
          inet addr:192.168.1.73  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21e:8cff:fe96:8793/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9683 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5677 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:2
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8543915 (8.5 MB)  TX bytes:951800 (951.8 KB)
          Memory:feac0000-feb00000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:430 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:430 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:39983 (39.9 KB)  TX bytes:39983 (39.9 KB)
```

Wireless card is definitely working - I can reboot in Windows and all is well.

I have edited /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and set
    [ifupdown]
    managed=true

All auto-detected updates are installed.

Any advice gratefully received!

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Thanks. Was fixed by the "I fixed my problem with the Broadcom bcm4311 drivers" comment.